# How can I export a nested interface?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I want to use interfaces which are related to a class as property of the class.

For example:

```
// file a.ts
// TODO how to export Options?
interface Options {
  ...
}


export default class A {
  constructor(options: A.Options) {
    ...
  }
}

// file b.ts
import A from 'a';

const options: A.Options = ...; // A.Options is the desired usage

const a = new A(options);
```

I only achieved this by using a `declare namespace`. The following code snippet allows me to use `A.Options`:

```
// file a.ts
declare namespace A {
  interface Options {
    ...
  }
}

class A {
  constructor(options: A.Options) {
    ...
  }
}

export default A;
```

But with that solution the [recommended tslint rule](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts) "no-namespace" complains it. I can allow the `declare namespace` with the additional tslint option ["allow-declarations"](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-namespace/).

Because of the tslint error I think that my approach is wrong.

What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the related [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) references.

> The main difference is that modules declare their dependencies.

and the reason:

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, modules are native part of the language, and should be supported by all compliant engine implementations. Thus, for new projects modules would be the recommended code organization mechanism.

With your example, I suggest the following:

```
// file a.ts
export interface Options {
  // ...
}

export class A {
    constructor(options: Options) {
    }
}

// file b.ts
import {A, Options as OptionsForClassA} from "./a";

const options: OptionsForClassA = { ... };

const a = new A(options);
```

Comment: Hm, I think I asked the question wrong. The main question is: How can I export a nested interface? I like it more to write `A.Options` than something like `OptionsForClassA`. Additional to that it easier for barrels (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/barrel.html). When I rexport more subfiles with an Options interface I have to rename (and maintain) all Options manually.
I will rework my question, so that the main questen is better to understood.